# Why can't I access a single website with Chrome, but with Firefox?

Tags: networking, google-chrome, firefox, ping

When I try to access https://www.sixt.de/ with Google Chrome, I get:

```
This page isn’t working
www.sixt.de is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

Other websites work for me. When I try to ping it, I get timeouts:

```
$ ping sixt.de
PING sixt.de (91.236.122.20) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- sixt.de ping statistics ---
263 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 262015ms
```

and

```
$ ping www.sixt.de
PING www-sixt-de.ax4z.com (91.236.122.20) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- www-sixt-de.ax4z.com ping statistics ---
175 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 175393ms
```

**But when I access it with Firefox, it works just fine.**

Do you have any idea what is going on? **How can I investigate that further?**

Comment: Is chrome up to date, proxy settings, firewall blocking it? http work? New profile with no extensions?

Comment: I didn't change anything in the network on my side, so I guess I can rule out proxy and my firewall. I installed uBlock a week ago... I'll check that later

Answer (score 0):

A 500 error strongly implies the problem is not on your side - it's an error generated by the server to say it's having problems.

It's probable the server is doing some kind of load balancing between multiple backends, and probably one of them is having problems. That would explain why some but not all your computers work.

You can try deleting cookies and/or a private browsing session or alternate browser to partially test this theory - it could be doing session management to a particular back-end based on cookies/session.